# How to trigger ValueChangeListener on the vaadin table?

Tags: listener, vaadin

The problem is, I cannot find listeners having been added to the table.
It seems the method getListeners doesn't work properly. It returns an empty collection.
My code:

```
table.addValueChangeListener(new MyListener());               
System.out.println("ListenerCount="+table.getListeners(ValueChangeListener.class).size());
```

Console output:

```
ListenerCount=0
```

What is wrong? I expected it would return 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AbstractComponent.getListeners`](https://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.alpha3/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#getListeners%28java.lang.Class%29) takes the *event type* class as an argument.

Pass it a [`Property.ValueChangeEvent`](https://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.alpha3/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/Property.ValueChangeEvent.html) or one of it's implementations, a [`Field.ValueChangeEvent`](https://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.alpha3/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/Field.ValueChangeEvent.html) or [`Label.ValueChangeEvent`](https://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.alpha3/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/Label.ValueChangeEvent.html), depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the API very carefully you'll see that you need to provide the event type of your listener:

```
java.util.Collection<?> getListeners(java.lang.Class<?> eventType)
```

> Returns all listeners that are registered for the given **event type**
>   or one of its subclasses.

In your case:

```
table.getListeners(ValueChangeEvent.class);
```